# MYSQL query with LIMIT, LEFT JOIN and SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS

Tags: mysql

Here's my query:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM designs AS d
    LEFT JOIN categories AS c
       ON d.category = c.category
    GROUP BY d.name ASC LIMIT 0, 10
```

I'd like return the number of rows found WITHOUT the limit condition in place. Here's my line of thinking:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS '0', *
    FROM designs AS d
    LEFT JOIN categories AS c
       ON d.category = c.category
    GROUP BY d.name ASC LIMIT 0, 10
UNION 
SELECT '1', FOUND_ROWS()
```

This doesn't work. I get a column # mismatch. How would I modify the query to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first select, is a:

```
SELECT '0', *
```

I don't know how many columns '*' is (at least 3, d.category, d.name, c.category), but your second query (after the union) should have the same number of columns. Now you only return two columns in your second query.

I also saw in the documentation, you should use an UNION ALL instead of UNION,  I quote:

> The value of FOUND_ROWS() is exact only if UNION ALL is used. If UNION without ALL is used, duplicate removal occurs and the value of FOUND_ROWS() is only approximate.

Comment: Yes, that's my problem (returning less columns in the second query) but I don't know how to make the columns # match OR find another 1 query solution whereby I would get the count of all rows without "limit" factored in. I can always run 2 queries but thought there may be a more elegant way.

Comment: Simply add more columns to your second query: SELECT '1', FOUND_ROWS() , NULL, NULL, NULL, ...., NULL. Besides, in my opinion it's a good practice to always define the columns you are retrieving from the database, instead of using the asterisk (*)